# Rendering a huge number of dynamic markers on leaflet after getting response takes a lot of time

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js to create a map view with dynamic markers. Everytime i get a response, i try to create dynamic components based on the data and uses changeDetector to detect changes. It works fine when the response data is not very large(around 500kb) but when the response data is more than that, the markers take a lot of time to render. For instance when the response is around 3-4 Mb , there are around 29k markers which take 2 mins to get rendered and hence my page takes around 3-4 mins to load which is not as per requirement.

I am using Angular framework. Is there some solution to decrease the rendering time for my dynamic components on the leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to canvas mode to increase performance https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-prefercanvas

Also explicitly set a `L.Canvas()` renderer https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-renderer

If that does not help, you might have to consider clustering your markers, since 28k markers is a lot to handle. You can use angular libs like https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Kyrix](https://github.com/tracyhenry/kyrix) which is designed to support marker clustering at scale. It needs to work with a database, but it also provides Docker containerization so you don't need to worry about installing and maintaining databases.

An example Kyrix app of 1.88 million wildfires on an interactive map: http://wildfire2.kyrixdemo.live/